# TikZ: find the right value of sample

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, diagrams, plot

Can you help me find the right value of the `samples` parameter? I would like to obtain a smooth curve passing through the intercept with the abscissa axis.

These are my three attempts: the `samples` range 50-140 produces a "Dimension too large" error

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
%\captionof{figure}{Metodo }
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
  legend pos=outer north east,
  legend cell align={left},
  xmax=8,xmin=0,
  ymax=1,ymin=0,
  yticklabels=\empty, xticklabels=\empty,
  width=8cm,
  height=6cm,
  axis lines = middle,
  set layers,
  x label style={at={(1,0)},right},
  y label style={at={(0,1)},above},
  xlabel={$T$},ylabel={$\xi$},
  y tick style={draw=none}, x tick style={draw=none},
  style={thick}
               ]              
        \addplot [blue,smooth,very thick,domain=0:7,samples=140] 
        {1-( (0.1*exp(-1/4)) *exp(1/x))};
        %\addplot[only marks, mark=*,fill=yellow] coordinates { (0,1.5) (2,2.3) (4,3.1) (6,3.9) (8,4.7) };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
  legend pos=outer north east,
  legend cell align={left},
  xmax=8,xmin=0,
  ymax=1,ymin=0,
  yticklabels=\empty, xticklabels=\empty,
  width=8cm,
  height=6cm,
  axis lines = middle,
  set layers,
  x label style={at={(1,0)},right},
  y label style={at={(0,1)},above},
  xlabel={$T$},ylabel={$\xi$},
  y tick style={draw=none}, x tick style={draw=none},
  style={thick}
               ]              
        \addplot [blue,smooth,very thick,domain=0:7,samples=50] 
        {1-( (0.1*exp(-1/4)) *exp(1/x))};
        %\addplot[only marks, mark=*,fill=yellow] coordinates { (0,1.5) (2,2.3) (4,3.1) (6,3.9) (8,4.7) };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
  legend pos=outer north east,
  legend cell align={left},
  xmax=8,xmin=0,
  ymax=1,ymin=0,
  yticklabels=\empty, xticklabels=\empty,
  width=8cm,
  height=6cm,
  axis lines = middle,
  set layers,
  x label style={at={(1,0)},right},
  y label style={at={(0,1)},above},
  xlabel={$T$},ylabel={$\xi$},
  y tick style={draw=none}, x tick style={draw=none},
  style={thick}
               ]              
        \addplot [blue,smooth,very thick,domain=0:7,samples=20] 
        {1-( (0.1*exp(-1/4)) *exp(1/x))};
        %\addplot[only marks, mark=*,fill=yellow] coordinates { (0,1.5) (2,2.3) (4,3.1) (6,3.9) (8,4.7) };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Are there better solutions than using the `samples` parameter?

Comment: Reverse direction,  i.e. starting with large x-values? Three attempts? I read 1. Please correct helo …

Comment: 140, 50 and 20 samples

Answer (score 4):

Your main problem is not the number of samples; it is the extremely large magnitude of the negative values computed when *x* approaches zero.

I propose to use `restrict y to domain=-10:1` plus a few other improvements (computing of the `0.1*exp(-1/4)` constant only once, drawing of the asymptote when *x* → +∞, *x* axis label position, removal of unused options...).

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\myConstFactor}{0.1*exp(-1/4)}% compute this only once
  \begin{axis}[
  ymax=1.5,
  extra y ticks={1},
  restrict y to domain=-10:1,
  width=8cm,
  height=6cm,
  axis lines = middle,
  xlabel={$T$}, ylabel={$\xi$},
  x label style={
    at={(current axis.right of origin)},
    anchor=west,
  },
  y label style={
    at={(current axis.above origin)},
    anchor=south,
  },
  style={thick}
  ]
  \addplot[blue, smooth, very thick, domain=0:7, samples=150]
    {1 - \myConstFactor*exp(1/x)};
  % Draw the asymptote for x → +∞
  \draw[red!80] (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}, 1) --
                (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}, 1);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Since you want to only show points with non-negative ordinates, we can use `restrict y to domain=0:1`. Note that the plot starts at a positive abscissa this time.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\myConstFactor}{0.1*exp(-1/4)}% compute this only once
  \begin{axis}[
  ymax=1.1,
  extra y ticks={1},
  restrict y to domain=0:1,
  width=8cm,
  height=6cm,
  axis lines = middle,
  xlabel={$T$}, ylabel={$\xi$},
  x label style={
    at={(current axis.right of origin)},
    anchor=west,
  },
  y label style={
    at={(current axis.above origin)},
    anchor=south,
  },
  style={thick},
  ]
  \addplot[blue, smooth, very thick, domain=0:7, samples=350]
    {1 - \myConstFactor*exp(1/x)};
  % Draw the asymptote for x → +∞
  \draw[red!80] (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}, 1) --
                (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}, 1);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, if you want the *x* axis to start at abscissa 0 but not to show any point with a negative ordinate, this can be done by adding for instance `xmin=0, extra x ticks={0}`:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\myConstFactor}{0.1*exp(-1/4)}% compute this only once
  \begin{axis}[
  xmin=0, extra x ticks={0},
  ymax=1.1, extra y ticks={1},
  restrict y to domain=0:1,
  width=8cm,
  height=6cm,
  axis lines = middle,
  xlabel={$T$}, ylabel={$\xi$},
  x label style={
    at={(current axis.right of origin)},
    anchor=west,
  },
  y label style={
    at={(current axis.above origin)},
    anchor=south,
  },
  style={thick},
  ]
  \addplot[blue, smooth, very thick, domain=0:7, samples=350]
    {1 - \myConstFactor*exp(1/x)};
  % Draw the asymptote for x → +∞
  \draw[red!80] (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}, 1) --
                (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}, 1);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! however, I should point out one thing: $\xi$ is a quantity (the extent of reaction, nr) between 0 and 1. Hence the need to consider only the positive semiaxis of the ordinates.

Comment: I've added a second plot showing only points with a positive ordinate.

Answer (score 1):

Following @MS-SPO, just put `0.15` instead of `0`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
%\captionof{figure}{Metodo }
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
  legend pos=outer north east,
  legend cell align={left},
  xmax=8,xmin=0,
  ymax=1,ymin=0,
  yticklabels=\empty, xticklabels=\empty,
  width=8cm,
  height=6cm,
  axis lines = middle,
  set layers,
  x label style={at={(1,0)},right},
  y label style={at={(0,1)},above},
  xlabel={$T$},ylabel={$\xi$},
  y tick style={draw=none}, x tick style={draw=none},
  style={thick}
               ]              
        \addplot [blue,smooth,very thick,domain=0.15:7,samples=200] 
        {1-( (0.1*exp(-1/4)) *exp(1/x))};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Essential the same answer as @frougon posted a couple of minutes ago, but I include it anyway as I made some additional corrections/changes.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=8cm, height=6cm,
xmin=0, xmax=8,
ymin=-2, ymax=1,
xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty,
axis lines=middle,
x label style={at={(xticklabel cs:1)}, below},
y label style={at={(yticklabel cs:1)}, above},
xlabel={$T$}, ylabel={$\xi$},
thick,
]              
\addplot [blue, very thick, domain=0:7, samples=100,  smooth, restrict y to domain=-10:1] {1-( (0.1*exp(-1/4)) *exp(1/x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph]

Comment: Nice! however, I should point out one thing: $\xi$ is a quantity (the extent of reaction, nr) between 0 and 1. Hence the need to consider only the positive semiaxis of the ordinates.

Comment: No problem - just change `ymin` back to `0`